# Preventing bash script from exiting after command error

Tags: shell-script, grep

I have a script that executes a command that outputs several lines of text:

```
qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --nas-get-serving-system
```

which outputs:

```
Registration state: 'registered'
    CS: 'detached'
    PS: 'detached'
    Selected network: 'unknown'
    Radio interfaces: '1'
            [0]: 'none'
    Data service capabilities: '0'
    Detailed status:
            Status: 'none'
            Capability: 'cs-ps'
            HDR Status: 'none'
            HDR Hybrid: 'yes'
            Forbidden: 'yes'
```

I want to check the string in quotes on the first line. If the string is equal to 'registered', I want to do something. So originally, I put this in my script:

```
qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --nas-get-serving-system | grep "'registered'"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    #do stuff
fi
```

This works, except every now and then, the qmicli command errors out (it's interfacing with an external device, and sometimes the hardware just doesn't respond when it should). When that happens, the whole script bombs out. So I OR'ed the qmicli command with `true` so it would be immune to error:

```
qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --nas-get-serving-system || true | grep "'registered'"
```

But now, $? is *always* 0, so I can't use the if conditional I had set up.

Is there a better way to check for a string within a multi-line output of a command, but also prevent the script for exiting if the command returns an error?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "bombs out".

Comment: Add `set -x` after `#!/bin/bash` or wrap the command+if statement into `set -x...set +x` code block, and run the script. That'll produce diagnostic output, and show where the problem lies. If that doesn't shine any light on the issue, consider running diagnostic with `strace that_script.sh`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I mean the script appears to exit and stop running. I *thought* it was default behavior for bash to exit a script if any single command errors out. But after reading muru's answer, I think I thought wrong as I don't have "set -e" anywhere. Now I'm thinking perhaps the hardware driver interface (through qmicli) is hanging or halting. Unfortunately, I have to wait until tomorrow morning to try the suggestions I've gotten here so far.

Comment: If you get warnings or errors, please include them verbatim in the question.

Comment: Do you have `set -e` in your script? If yes, remove it.

Answer (score 16):

I assume you have `set -e` or equivalent in the script, so it exits if a command fails.

Now this is unidiomatic:

```
some command
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ...
```

It's an unnecessarily roundabout way of doing:

```
if some command; then ...
```

A command in the test part of an `if` statement does not trigger `set -e` if it fails, because that would defeat the point of the `if` statement.
From [the Bash docs for `-e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the
>   command list immediately following a `while` or `until` keyword, part of
>   the test in an `if` statement, part of any command executed in a `&&` or
>   `||` list except the command following the final `&&` or `||`, any command
>   in a pipeline but the last, or if the command’s return status is being
>   inverted with `!`.

So if you do:

```
if qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --nas-get-serving-system | grep "'registered'"; then
    #do stuff
fi
```

`qmicli` failing will not trigger `set -e`.

---

(Also, I don't think it's `qmicli` failing that's causing the problem - it's `qmicli` failing in such a way as to make the `grep` command fail that's causing the problem.)

Comment: Hm, I don't explicitly have set -e in the script. I thought exiting on error was default behavior for bash. Now I'm a little more confused.

Comment: Could be the shebang has `#! /bin/bash -e`. If not, please post a minimal script that reproduces the problem.

Comment: if `qmcli` here fails without producing any output, the `grep` will not match any lines, and will exit with a status of `1`, which is falsy.